# How the get the filepath of a document in setFieldName of PDFTextStream?

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, indexing, filepath

I have a problem I´m working with `PDFTextStream` and `Lucene` to index pdf files. The problem is a build a text with the methods of `PDFTextStream` but I can't get the filepath of the documents stored in the directory where I am indexing the files, I have tried with:

`setFieldName(file.getPath(),"path");` but I can´t get the file path. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
public class PDFDocument {
//Constructor vacío
 IndexWriter writer;
 File directorio;
public PDFDocument(){
    directorio= new File("C:/indexpdf");
}
/*Metódo estático para agregar un documento PDF a un IndexWriter de Lucene
 * pasando como parámetros IndexWriter, y el archivo PDF
 */

public void agregarPDFaIndex() throws IOException{
    writer= new IndexWriter(new File("C:/indexpdfsalida"), new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
    //Se crea e inicializa una nueva instancia de DocumentFactoryCofig
    DocumentFactoryConfig config= new DocumentFactoryConfig();;


    config.setCopyAllPDFAttrs(false);
    //los datos del documento PDF se almacenan, se tokenizan y se indexan
    config.setPDFAttrSettings(true, true, true);
    /*Se configuran los nombre explicitos que deben ser usados en los Fields 
     * que crean una nueva instancia de un Document de Lucene        * 
     */
    File[] files= directorio.listFiles();

    for(File file: files){
        if(file.canRead() && !file.isDirectory() && file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")){
            System.out.println("Indexando el archivo: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            config.setMainTextFieldName("content");
            Document doc= new Document();

            config.setTextSettings(false, true, true);
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_AUTHOR, "autor");
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_CREATION_DATE, "fecha_creacion");
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_MOD_DATE,"ultimo_mod");
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_TITLE,"titulo");
            config.setFieldName(DocumentFactoryConfig.DEFAULT_MAIN_TEXT_FIELD_NAME, "content");
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_CREATOR,"creador");
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_PRODUCER, "productor");
            config.setFieldName(PDFTextStream.ATTR_SUBJECT, "asunto");
            config.setFieldName(file.getPath(), "path");

            doc= PDFDocumentFactory.buildPDFDocument(file, config);

            System.out.println(doc.get("path"));
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
    }
    writer.optimize();
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("OK");

}
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    PDFDocument doc= new PDFDocument();
    doc.agregarPDFaIndex();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. I have edited your question to make a few things clearer. please make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any constants you could use in `PDFTextStream`. It would, however, be pretty simple to add it directly to the Lucene document that is generated by `PDFDocumentFactory` before adding it to the index:

```
doc= PDFDocumentFactory.buildPDFDocument(file, config);

doc.addField(new StringField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));

System.out.println(doc.get("path"));
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

You may want to use a different field type, depending on your needs (`StringField` for exact matching, `TextField` for full text search, `StoredField` for no searching on that field)

Comment: thank you! I did not think I can use doc.addField (); PDFTextStream using, but now I know, thanks you for your answer!